# How to change ion-icon for material design similar to ios-outline?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, ionicons

I want to use only ion-icon but these are made differently for different devices such as if we look for notifications ion-icon then we find for ion, ios-outline and material design.
In material desgin all the icons are filled with black color instaead I want to use similar to ios-outline icons in my material designs.

How can I use them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question. To use the ios version of the icon, you'll need to use the `ios-` prefix like `<ion-icon name=ios-notifications"></ion-icon>`. However, some of the icons are not available on ios so you'll need to refer to the [ionic reference site](https://ionicframework.com/docs/ionicons/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ios icons by using the name, in this case `<ion-icon name=ios-notifications"></ion-icon>` directly.  Note that this will only use the one icon and not change by the platform to match the common icons on each platform.

If you want to just use the iOS versions, then this [Ionic Framework Reference](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-specific-styles/) will show you how to do that.